# PHP sha512 hmac produces different value than JS hmac

Tags: javascript, php, authorization, hmac, sha512

Here is some of my JS code. I am creating the hmac using Crypto, then passing in the date and signature as request headers to use in PHP:

```js
events: {
    proxyReq: (proxyReq, req) => {
        const date = Date.now();
        const API_KEY = 125;
        const API_SECRET_KEY = 'abc';
        const s = new Buffer(API_SECRET_KEY, 'base64');
        const message = req.method + req.url + date;
        let hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha512', s);
        const signature = hmac.update(message).digest('base64');
        proxyReq.setHeader('x-api-key', API_KEY);
        proxyReq.setHeader('x-api-signature', signature);
        proxyReq.setHeader('x-api-date', date);
    },
},
```

Here is my PHP function where I try to reproduce the same hmac using hash_hmac():

```
public function handle($request, \Closure $next)
{
    try {
        $API_SECRET_KEY = 'abc';
        $method = $request->method();
        $url = $request->path();
        $date = $request->header('x-api-date');
        $client_key = $request->header('x-api-key');
        $client_signature = $request->header('x-api-signature');
        $message = $method . $url . $date;

        $hmac = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha512', $message, base64_decode($API_SECRET_KEY), true));

        $all['x-api-date'] = $date;
        $all['x-api-signature'] = $client_signature;
        $all['x-api-key'] = $client_key;

        Log::error($client_signature);
        Log::error($hmac);

    return $next($request);
}
```

My last outputs:

```
[2018-07-10 14:23:57] local.ERROR: D0xis7BbxLBg6eWBlIT0ZSnhzk4c3Z3Ore9B16bNZow8xoinfM1zuMlS+lZ6pcOqRRHuupodUVFAIHfv89v4xw==  
[2018-07-10 14:23:57] local.ERROR: Uypk5ZAd/I6E6sMi9UjIMyMxVhuQm7MatZbKCcGjGjsE2JqqrvTRYuJAR/SSde10eHAkPIz0g24CSZp0G+833A==
```

Can someone explain to me what I am doing wrong? I made sure to use base64 encoding/decoding and made sure the values passed into the hmac function were the same as the headers.

I appreciate any help!

Comment: Looks like you encode on the client with a key of `125`, but on the server you use `abc`.

Comment: @bc1105 I am using 'abc' as secret key. I set both api_secret to 'abc'. Sorry about that, I should keep my variables consistent and noticeable. Fixed it for better readability.